# json object to array of strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have the following JSON:

```
{
"tagExpression": "@debug",
"project": "Project_PERSONAL"
}
```

And I need to convert it to the following array of strings:

```
[ "tagExpression:@debug",
"project: Project_PERSONAL"  ]
```

This is the code I wrote, and i would like to know maybe is a better way to do it, the code read the JSON from a file, then performs a for loop to convert it:

```
logger.info(`Updating run configuration base on process args`);
let path = String(processArgvHelper.getArgValue("overrideConf"));
let fileconf =  JSON.parse(require("fs").readFileSync(path));
let fileConfStr = String(Object.entries(fileconf)).split(",");   
let fileConfArr = [];
for(let i=0;i<fileConfStr.length;i++){
  logger.info(`${fileConfStr[i]} -- ${i}`);
  if(i === 0 || (i%2)==0){
    fileConfArr.push(`${fileConfStr[i]}:${fileConfStr[i+1]}`);
    logger.info(`${fileConfStr[i]}:${fileConfStr[i+1]}`)
  }      
}
```

Then fileConfArr contains the desired converted array of strings.

Comment: all the solution until now give the following:
{"0":"tagExpression","1":"@debug","2":"project","3":"Project_PERSONAL"}, but i need as i said the following:
[ "tagExpression:@debug",
"project: Project_PERSONAL"  ]

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the object keys and then map it together

```js
var myObject = {
"tagExpression": "@debug",
"project": "Project_PERSONAL"
}


var result = Object.keys(myObject).map(function(key) {
  return key + ':' + myObject[key];
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
Object.entries(obj).map(([k,v])=> `${k}:${v}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a for in loop to iterate over an object and then push key and the corresponding value to the resultant array

```js
var input = {
  tagExpression: "@debug",
  project: "Project_PERSONAL"
};
var out = [];
for (var key in input) {
  out.push(`${key}: ${input[key]}`);
}
console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for this solution.

```js
const jsonData = `{
"tagExpression": "@debug",
"project": "Project_PERSONAL"
}`;
const obj = JSON.parse(jsonData);

const result = Object.keys(obj).reduce((arr, key) => {
  let str = `${key}: ${obj[key]}`;
  arr.push(str);
  return arr;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you extract the keys into an array

Then map each key and return a key and value

### Here is the code snippet

```
let fileconf = {
   "tagExpression": "@debug",
   "project": "Project_PERSONAL"
 }
 let arrOfkeys = Object.keys(fileconf);
 let fileConfArr = arrOfkeys.map(key => key + fileconf[key]);
```

### fileconf[key] returns the value of that key

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's better, or how to define "better" for this, but i would do it like this:

```
let stringifiedJson = JSON.stringify(fileConf);
let stringWithoutBrackets = stringifiedJson.substring(1, stringifiedJson.length - 1);
let finalArray = stringWithoutBrackets.split(',').map(it => it.replace(/\"/g, ""));
```